# nginx limit_req_zone doesn't seem to work

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup a global limit to a certain uri using nginx via openresty

with the following config, if I curl this box I get a 204 no matter how many times I request it per minute.
    worker_processes  1;
    error_log logs/error.log;

```
events {
}

http {
    log_format spec_format '$request_uri $const $status';
    access_log logs/access.log spec_format;#off;
    resolver 10.0.0.2;

    limit_req_log_level error;
    limit_req_zone  $const  zone=one:100k   rate=1r/m;

    server {
        set $const 1;

        listen 80;


        location / {
            return 200 "invalid url";
        }

        location ~* /request/? {
            limit_req   zone=one  burst=1 nodelay;
            return 204;
        }


        location /health/ {
            return 200 "healthy";
        }
    }
}
```

From the docs I can't find anything obvious (Ive tried switching things around a lot).

In case it helps, the box is running on AWS behind an EIP and Ubuntu 13.10. I'm using openresty-1.5.8.1 from openresty.org.

Also, the actual limit I want to work is for around 24000r/s and there are other settings I thought might be conflicting, but even stripped down it doesn't behave like I thought it should.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that `$const` is not yet set when `limit_req_zone` processes it. Are you seeing the correct `$cost` value in the log?

The limit_req_module will [ignore empty values](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html), from the docs:

> The key is any non-empty value of the specified variable (empty values
>   are not accounted).